# How do I get a MP3 file's details (like the author, title, album, year, etc.) with not too complicated coding?

Tags: delphi, mp3, delphi-7, mplayer

I just want a simple piece of code that can give me the author, album, year, title and genre from a mp3 file. If one can, in the form of variables so that I can work with that. All I want to do is let this information show in a label. Eg. lblArtist, lblAlbum, lblGenre, lblYear, lblTitle. If any one can give me some help, I wo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information you want is called [ID3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3).  This site has many answers for this (in many languages).  For example, [How to read MP3 file tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645803/how-to-read-mp3-file-tags)

Answer (score 1):

> - How to Read / Write ID3 Tags in MP3 Files [1](http://www.delphifaq.net/how-to-readwrite-id3-tags-in-mp3-files/) - [2](http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/f92.shtml) - [3](http://aprendedelphipt.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-to-readwrite-id3-tags-in-mp3-files.html)
> - [Your first MP3 Delphi player](http://delphi.about.com/od/multimedia/l/aa112800d.htm)
> - [ID3v2 Library is a component for use in Win32](http://www.3delite.hu/Object%20Pascal%20Developer%20Resources/id3v2library.html)
> - James Webb [ID3v2.3.0](http://www.torry.net/vcl/mmedia/audio/id3v2.zip) & [ID3v2.4.0](http://www.torry.net/vcl/mmedia/audio/id3v4.zip) Delphi library
> - [PBB Player ( pbb-player ) - ID3v2adv.pas](http://www.koders.com/delphi/fidA2D0DF0E9569EE0B80A424CA8A5D940196BB9C32.aspx?s=xml)

---

Related Stackoverflow:

> - [Extract Album Art from mp3 and display in an Image with Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394678/extract-album-art-from-mp3-and-display-in-an-image-with-delphi)
> - [How to edit mp3 file details (Delphi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259961/how-to-edit-mp3-file-details-delphi)

Comment: hi DelphiBeginner_XD see my update. ps next time tell us what language are you using first ;)

Comment: Hehe, sorry. Will do that next time. Thanx. :)

Answer (score 1):

MP3 tags are in [ID3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) format, so that is what you are after.

More related stackoverflow questions:

- [Universal MP3 and WMA tag reader for Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406246/universal-mp3-and-wma-tag-reader-for-delphi)
- [FAQ tagged ID3](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/id3/faq)

Personally I love the [BASS library](http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html), but that does much more audio stuff, so it is only worth the effort if you want to do more (like playing, mixing, effects and such). It does those things in an excellent way though. Bass hand wrappers in many languages and platforms, including Delphi, .NET, Windows, iOS, just to name a few..

--jeroen